# Getting a list of existing Rails Error classes for re-use/inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, custom-exceptions

Often I need to throw a custom(ized) error. Like when a resource cannot be found due to a mismatch in parameters or so.

I prefer to throw existing errors or, throw an error that is inherited from an existing error. That way, I don't introduce Error classes that were already defined and could have been used perfectly (DRY). But it also allows to keep wording and style the same, by inheriting and simply changing a word or two to clarify the difference with the original Error.

For example:

```
Foo.new
Foo.some_external_id = nil
Foo.fetch_external_resource
# => InvalidOptions: Calling Foo#fetch_external_resource with nil is invalid
```

I am quite sure such errors are already defined. In fact, after reading trough many lines of code, I found my MongoID driver has `Mongoid::Errors::InvalidOptions: Calling Document#find with nil is invalid`.

Is there a list of available Error classes in Ruby Core and Ruby on Rails? Is there a way to get such a list for your current project?

Is it smart at all to re-use and/or inherit existing errors, or should I maintain my own, custom set instead?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's a mostly adequate solution here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/158088

Since this question is unanswered, yet coming up at the top of Google search results, I decided to wrap Frederick Cheung's solution up in a rake task and post it here.

Drop the following in **lib/tasks/exceptions.rake**

```
namespace :exceptions do
  task :list => :environment do
    exceptions = []

    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |k|
      exceptions << k if k.ancestors.include?(Exception)
    end

    puts exceptions.sort { |a,b| a.to_s <=> b.to_s }.join("\n")
  end
end
```

Run it with:

```
bundle exec rake exceptions:list
```

*If you're still on Rails 2, or not using Bundler, leave off the `bundle exec`*

This list is probably adequate, but not exhaustive.  For example, ActiveResource defines several exceptions such as `ActiveResource::ConnectionError` and `ActiveResource::TimeoutError` that are not appearing when I run this task.  Maybe someone else can enlighten me as to why.

Comment: It may not be exhaustive, but is sufficient for me, for now. Thanks a lot. And thanks for the link to the list.

Answer (score 49):

While this list may change, and it's best to still use Ryan's solution, the list for Rails 4 (limited to Rails classes and not other gems):

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError
AbstractController::Error
AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods::MissingHelperError
ActionController::ActionControllerError
ActionController::BadRequest
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
ActionController::MethodNotAllowed
ActionController::MissingFile
ActionController::NotImplemented
ActionController::ParameterMissing
ActionController::RedirectBackError
ActionController::RenderError
ActionController::RoutingError
ActionController::SessionOverflowError
ActionController::UnknownController
ActionController::UnknownFormat
ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters
ActionController::UrlGenerationError
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow
ActionDispatch::IllegalStateError
ActionDispatch::Journey::Router::RoutingError
ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError
ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::IpSpoofAttackError
ActionDispatch::Session::SessionRestoreError
ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper::InvalidNumberError
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotFound
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch
ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignmentError
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError
ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationVersionError
ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError
ActiveRecord::HasAndBelongsToManyAssociationForeignKeyNeeded
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPointlessSourceTypeError
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicThroughError
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateNewRecords
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantDissociateNewRecords
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError
ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection
ActiveRecord::IllegalMigrationNameError
ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey
ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors
ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyAssociation
ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
ActiveRecord::Rollback
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch
ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseAlreadyExists
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseNotSupported
ActiveRecord::ThrowResult
ActiveRecord::TransactionIsolationError
ActiveRecord::Transactions::TransactionError
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError
ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey
ActiveRecord::WrappedDatabaseException
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError
ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer::SafeConcatError
ActiveSupport::XMLConverter::DisallowedType
```

Answer (score 9):

A shorter option is available in Rails [thanks to ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/descendants):

```
puts Exception.descendants.sort_by(&:name)
```

You can also check out the source to see how they handle it.

Comment: Nice!! This is the real answer.